# Dynamically changing glues in Cucumber JUnit 4 for CucumberOptions

Tags: java, junit, junit4, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I wonder if there is any way I can add new glues during the steps. I have one step that should add new packages depending on the result so I cannot give my options as CucumberOptions.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/featureFiles/Employee_WeeklySchedule.feature"},
    glue = { "magictester.core.glues" }
    plugin = {"html:target/results" },
    tags = {"@Runme"}
)
```

How can that be done? How can add/remove glues to cucumberOptions after test started?